# Привязка работает только при запуске программы

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Значение свойства `Text` меняется только один раз - при запуске программы. Далее оно остается таким же, как при запуске. как привязать TextBox к `Text` так, чтобы `Text` всегда был равен тексту внутри TextBox?

```
<UserControl x:Class="prod_bw.Ctrls.UpDownCtrl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:prod_bw.Ctrls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" Height="22"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:UpDownCtrl,IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="22">
        <TextBox x:Name="value" Width="32" Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}" MaxLength="3" /> <!-- * -->
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

```cs
namespace prod_bw.Ctrls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для UpDownCtrl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UpDownCtrl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private static readonly Regex onlyNumberRegex = new Regex("[^0-9]");

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public string Text { get; set; } // *

        public UpDownCtrl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите ответ на прошлый вопрос, я там дописал полезного. Вам нужна либо реализация `INotifyPropertyChanged` (ссылка в позапрошлом ответе), либо `DependencyProperty` (ссылка в прошлом ответе).

Comment: @aepot, здесь же есть реализация INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Вот вы создали метод `OnPropertyChanged`, а вам не кажется подозрительным, что он нигде не вызывается. Ссылки на примеры я уже вам давал, см. позапрошлый ответ.

Comment: Вот ещё примеров https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A373567+INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: У свойств есть геттер (`get`) и сеттер (`set`), которые вызываются при чтении значения из свойства (геттер) и записи значения в свойство (сеттер). Вот при изменении свойства, вы обязаны в его сеттере задать вызов метода оповещения от INPC. Тут нет магии, за свойствами не следят. Если прям хотите, чтоб было все само и в пару строк кода - генерация кода вам в помощь.